# Disable right click except some elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this code to disable right click on my page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
       return false;
    });
});
```

How can i add some exception, lets say when you right click on image the context menu should not be disabled.

Maybe something with stopPropagation but can't figure it out.

Thanks

Comment: I have edited your title. Please do not include information about a language used in a question title unless it wouldn't make sense without it. Tags serve this purpose. Also see, ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/19190/193440), where the consensus is "no, they should not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using JQuery event.target to work with children](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17756811/using-jquery-event-target-to-work-with-children)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

with `event.target`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).bind("contextmenu", function(e) {
     if(!$(e.target).is('img')){
        return false;
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: Not method is not working. The target method is working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () { 
      $('#btnClick').bind('contextmenu',function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert('Right Click is not allowed');
      }); 

    });
  </script>



 <input type="text" /><br>
    <input type="checkbox" />

  <button id="btnClick">Click</button>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NLJ6t/1/